# Solving an ODE by inspection

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following ODE by inspection
$$(x-1)y''-xy'+y=0$$

So that method that is recommended is to guess the general form.

**EDIT :** If you guess the general form $y=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2$. Substitute in the main equation and solve for $c_1,c_2,c_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Just execute the computation. There are several solutions. $f(x)=ax$ works for all $a \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a second order equation and you need to find a family of solutions with two independent parameters.

First observe that the equation is linear so that the general solution will be a linear combination of two independent particular solutions.

Then as the coefficients are polynomials is $x$, you first try polynomial solutions. Take the monomials by increasing degree:

- $1$ doesn't fit.
- $x$ is fine, we're lucky.
- $x^2$ yields $2(x-1)-2x^2+x^2=2(x-1)-x^2$, won't do as there is no cancellation of $x^2$.
- $x^n$ won't do better, for a similar reason.

Now we have exhausted the possibilities with polynomials and we need to look elsewhere.

Rewriting the equation

$$x(y''-y')-y''+y=0$$
we try to rub out the term in $x$ by achieving $y''=y'$. We are glad to see that the solution candidate $y=e^x$, is compatible with $-y''+y=0$.

Then
$$y=ae^x+bx.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If you notice that the equation can write $$x(y''-y')+(y-y'')=0$$ $y=ke^x$ seems also to be a good candidate since $\frac{d^n(k e^x)}{dx^n}=ke^x$.

So, taking into account wythagoras's answer, the general solution seems to be $$y=c_1x+c_2 e^x$$